# Complex-valued continuous is holomorphic as an integral.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, analytic-functions

I've been thinking about the following problem. If $f$ is continuous on the entire complex plane, is it necessarily true that the function $G_R(w)= \int_0^w f(z)dz$ is holomorphic on the closed disk of radius $R$ centered at 0?  The real-valued analogue holds, but complex is alittle more delicate it seems. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I've tried applying the definition and Morerra's theorem, each without success.

Comment: See what happens with the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Do be careful to choose appropriate tags. This is very clearly not real analysis.

Comment: If I use the formulation of the Cauchy-Riemann equations $\partial g /\partial \overline{w}=0$, it definitely appears to hold, but I'm still a bit skeptical.

Comment: @m2271r could post your result? I have got the feeling you need that $f$ is Lipschitz or differentiable.

Comment: You're probably right. I simply said that $\partial g(w)/ \partial \overline{w} = d/d \overline{w}(\int_0^w f(z)dz) =0$. I expect it's wrong; I didn't want to fight with figuring out how to separate g into real and imaginary parts.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the integral is taken over the line segment from $0$ to $w$.

Let $f(z) = \bar z$. Then $f$ is continuous on the complex plane, but
$$
G(w) = \int_0^w \bar z\,dz = \int_0^1 \overline{t w} \, w \, dt = \frac12 |w|^2
$$
which is not holomorphic on any disc. (I used the parametrization $t \mapsto t\,w$).

Comment: Excellent, thank you. That tends to be the prototypic example for such things. Thank you!